# Java- Can you get multiple variables using one JOptionPane message?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am working on a project for homework and it is a simple lottery program. The program must ask for six numbers using JOptionPane and they must be less than 60. My question is could I get all six numbers using only ONE JOPtionPane input?

The program uses random number generators to compare the six input numbers to.

Comment: You can use the same `JOptionPane` instance six times in a loop, if that what you are asking about.

Comment: @nachokk: yes, this is possible. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible. The `message` parameter to the various `showXXX()` methods is defined as `Object`. If you pass a Swing component as the "message" it will be displayed properly:

Something like:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JCheckBox cbx = JCheckBox("Option 1");
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
panel.add(cbx);
panel.add(tf);
... add more controls
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialg(yourFrame, panel, "Dialog titel", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
{
   boolean doStuff = cbx.isSelected();
   String someValue = tv.getText();
   ... process other options here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this, and can adjust it accordingly

```
public class JOptionPaneMulti {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JTextField Field1 = new JTextField(5);
      JTextField Field2 = new JTextField(5);
      JTextField Field3 = new JTextField(5);
      JTextField Field4 = new JTextField(5);

      JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
      myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
      myPanel.add(new JLabel("input 1:"));
      myPanel.add(Field1);
      myPanel.add(new JLabel("input 2:"));
      myPanel.add(Field2);
      myPanel.add(new JLabel("input 3:"));
      myPanel.add(Field3);
      myPanel.add(new JLabel("input 4:"));
      myPanel.add(Field4);

      int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, 
               "Please Enter Values", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
      if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
         System.out.println("1 value: " + Field1.getText());
         System.out.println("2 value: " + Field2.getText());
         System.out.println("3 value: " + Field3.getText());
         System.out.println("4 value: " + Field4.getText());
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: @user3303096 Please vote up and mark this answer as accepted. To show your problem is solved. If this answer is valid or and accordingly what you ask for. see [why voting is important](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 1):

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` returns a String, so you could `split` the  return value.

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
String[] array = input.split("\\s+");
```

Check if the array length is six and also if they're all numbers. Put it in a `while` loop until both of those conditions are met. If not keep showing the dialog. If they *are* met then then do something with that input.

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
int num3 = Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
...
```

- See [**`String.split()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) if you are unfamiliair with this method.
- See [**Arrays**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) if you're unfamiliar with arrays.
- See [**`while` loops**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) if you unfamiliar with them.